# Creating Object from text file

Tags: java

I am creating a function to load in a text file, the problem is that instead of what you would expect from a text file format (name|id|address|etc) it is presented like this;

> Obe Two Canobi
>
> Specialist
>
> false
>
> JK001
>
> 125
>
> F010
>
> on task
>
> Programming and Computer Support

Down a text file, My program must be able to load any amount of this group of 8. Here is what I have come up with but doesnt work for whatever reason, it will re-load the same lines from the first input from what ive printed.

```
 //Custom function to load files from given inputs
public static void loadFile(String location,String file,String type) {
    //Using try/catch to retrieve errors
    WorkUnit[] wu = null;
    try {
        //Using the buffered reader to load the file.
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\kenji\\IdeaProjects\\Assingment01C_LaTrobe\\src\\workunit.txt")));
            lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);

            int length = lnr.getLineNumber() + 1;
            print(length + "");

            lnr.close();

            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "C:\\Users\\kenji\\IdeaProjects\\Assingment01C_LaTrobe\\src\\workunit.txt" ));
            wu = new WorkUnit[length/8];
            print(wu.length + "");
            String currentLine;
            for(int i=0;i<length/8;i+=8) {
                Crew cr = new Crew();
                Ship ship = new Ship();
                cr.setName(in.readLine());
                cr.setClassification(getCrewClassification(in.readLine()));
                cr.setStatus(getTrueFalse(in.readLine()));
                cr.setId(in.readLine());
                cr.setPoints(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
                ship.setId(in.readLine());
                ship.setShipStatus(getShipStatus(in.readLine()));
                ship.setPurpose(in.readLine());
                wu[i] = new WorkUnit(ship,cr);
                print(wu[i].toString());
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    for(int i = 0; i < wu.length;i++) {
        print(wu[i].toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
16
2
WorkUnit{ship=Ship{id='F010', purpose='Programming and Computer Support', shipStatus=on_task}, crew=Crew{id='JK001', name='Obe Two Canobi', experiencePoints=125, status=false, classification=Specialised}, available=true}
WorkUnit{ship=Ship{id='F010', purpose='Programming and Computer Support', shipStatus=on_task}, crew=Crew{id='JK001', name='Obe Two Canobi', experiencePoints=125, status=false, classification=Specialised}, available=true}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SpaceCity.loadFile(SpaceCity.java:131)
    at SpaceCity.addMenuChoice(SpaceCity.java:81)
    at SpaceCity.MainMenu(SpaceCity.java:32)
    at SpaceCity.main(SpaceCity.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List wu has 2 spaces, But i hops by eight. change the code

```
for(int i=0;i<length/8;i+=8) {
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<length/8;i++) {
```